# get list of recent apps that were launched by user

Tags: java, android

in my app ,i want to get a list of apps that were recently launched by user.
for now,just log this list.

i searched about it.
and i found this code:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcessInfo) {
            Log.d("Nitin", processInfo.processName);
        }
```

but this code only prints my app name. i.e com.tracker.appcount.apptracker
so it means that my runningProcessInfo list is only of size 1.

i don't know where i am wrong?repeatedly i saw answer of this format.and in some posts it was accomplished using **getRecentsTasks** function which is now **deprecated** so it's of no use.
please help me on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Evrything is deprecated for security reasons. If you want to know about things happening on your phone, root it and use a shell to get what you need

Comment: it's not about to know **things** about my phone.
i am trying to make an app and i am stuck at this point.
getting a list is just a part of that app.